# difference between color and map-get method in scss

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I have been working on theming part of an ionic 3 application. As part of this I am refactoring the colors.

In order to map the colors based on key I've seen `color` and `map-get`  functions however I couldn't get any documentation on the exact use case.

Can anyone help me with understanding the difference between `map-get` vs `color` function.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Please see the below sample SCSS.

```css
// Override default colors
$colors: (
    primary:    green,
    secondary:  blue,
    danger:     red,
);

.primary{
  background-color:color($colors, primary);
}
.secondary{
  background-color:map-get($colors, secondary);
}
.danger{
  background-color:color($colors, danger);
}
```